# App Management Service error with Workflow can use app permissions Feature

Tags: 2019, workflow-manager, service-applications

Workflow Manager, App Management Service and Workflow can use app permissions were all functioning correctly.  Then, to test my service creation scripts, I deleted all the services.  I recreated all the services and reconnected Workflow Manager.  However, I was unable to disable, then enable, Workflow can use app permissions.  When I look in the ULS, there is an error when going to a URL.  The URL is supposed to point to the IIS Application for App Management: IIS -> Sites -> SharePoint Web Services -> (GUID).  The correct address is: _api/(new Guid)/AppMng.  However, the ULS has: _api/(Deleted Service GUID)/AppMng.  When I look at the Services and Proxies in PowerShell, I can find the Service with (new Guid) but I can't find anything with (Deleted Service GUID).

Does anyone know how to convince SharePoint to use (new Guid) instead of (Deleted Service GUID)?

Also, Workflows can use app permissions is the only feature that is affected; at least, that I've found.

Answer (score 0):

After looking carefully, again, in PowerShell at Get-SPServiceApplicationProxy, I found an orphaned Proxy.  After running Remove-SPServiceApplicationProxy on the Proxy, I recreated App Management Service and now everything is working.